# Problems removing dictionaries from list in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a couple of pieces of logic within my code where I remove either a key/value or dictionary if the conditions are met.  These objects remove while they are in the list, but once they are appended to a top level dictionary and turned into a JSON object, they re-appear, hence negating my logic.  What could be the cause of this?

Here is my code sample showing how the dictionaries are appended logic removing keys/values and dictionaries;

```
dL311 = dict()
d = dict()
d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_1)
d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_1 )
d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_1)
l311.append(d)
dL311 = dict()
d = dict()
d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_2)
d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_2)
d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_2)
l311.append(d)
d = dict()
d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_3)
d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_3)
d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_3)
l311.append(d)
d = dict()
d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_4)
d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_4)
d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_4)
l311.append(d)
d = dict()
d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_5)
d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_5)
d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_5)
l311.append(d)
d = dict()
d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_6)
d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_6)
d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_6)
l311.append(d)
d = dict()
d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_7)
d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_7)
d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_7)
l311.append(d)
d = dict()
d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_8)
d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_8)
d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_8)
l311.append(d)
d = dict()
d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_9)
d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_9)
d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_9)
l311.append(d)
d = dict()
d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_10)
d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_10)
d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_10)
l311.append(d)

for d in l311:
    if(d['Name'].strip() == '') and((type(d['DACItemCount']) != int) or (d['DACItemCount']==0)):
        del d['Name']
        del d['DACItemCount']

lIndexes = []
nCnt = len(l311)
for i in range(nCnt):
    dd = l311[i]
    if(dd==d):
        lIndexes.append(i)


for i in lIndexes:
    i

#remove the d from the original l311 in a reverse order:
# print ("order (of index) in which items are deleted:" )
for ii in reversed(lIndexes):
    if  d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_10) == ' ':
        # print(ii)
        del l311[ii]


print  (l311)


dL311 = dict()
dL311.setdefault("DeadAnimalRemoval", l311)
dResult.setdefault("ListOfLa311DeadAnimalRemoval",dL311)

#Ends of adding additional itmes ****************************************
lResults.append({"MetaData": {}, "SRData": dResult})
```

Example Output using the code above;

```
[{'Name': '071920150633557841', 'DACType': ' ', 'DriverLastName': 'Aguilar', 'DriverFirstName': 'SA', 'LastUpdatedBy': 'SANSTAR1', 'DACItemCount': '0', 'Type': 'Dead Animal Removal'}]
```

JSON output without removed dictionaries;

```
{
        "MetaData": {}, 
        "SRData": {
            "ListOfLa311DeadAnimalRemoval": {
                "DeadAnimalRemoval": [
                    {
                        "DACItemCount": "0", 
                        "DACType": " ", 
                        "DriverFirstName": "SA", 
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                        "Name": "071920150633557841", 
                        "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "DACType": " ", 
                        "DriverFirstName": "SA", 
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                        "Name": " ", 
                        "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "ReasonCode": "", 
            "ResolutionCode": "A", 
            "SRNumber": "1-21630001"
        }
    }
]
```

I am expecting to have the second dictionary removed since there is no 'Name' value.

Comment: Major rule of Python (and programming in general): ***DRY*** Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: Ummm... all of the `d = dict(); d.setdefault...` business perhaps?

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Loops. Most of the lines are the same in each dict, so repeating them is wasteful, time-consuming, and very difficult to maintain if you ever want to change something. I would assume the `dar_uid_*` and `dar_qyt_*` variables are being generated individually someplace else - they should be in another iterable like a list instead, which would then be iterated over in your loop.

Comment: If you find yourself making things like `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, etc., you should be using an iterable like a list, dict, or similar.

Comment: You make many references to the variable d in the code after your original definitions, and after the first loop with "d in l311". This doesn't make any sense, because d has no clear meaning in that context. Perhaps the indenting was broken when you copied your code here. If not, there's clearly something wrong with the intended flow of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a name, then `if  d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_10) == ' '` will add the name back -- as dar_uid_10.  Unless dar_uid_10 == ' ', then this code will never think that a dictionary has a name that is a space.

Just use `if 'Name' not in d` instead, I think.